# Uniq many files in place

Tags: bash, unix

I have many `*.dat` files. What's a bash script that could remove duplicate adjacent lines in each one?

Comment: ... What's wrong with `uniq`?

Comment: I don't think I can specify many output files according to a regex like *.dat.

Comment: Then you need to specify that the issue you're having is that you don't know how to iterate through the files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in "$@"
do
   cp "$f" /tmp/tmp.dat
   uniq /tmp/tmp.dat > "$f"
done
```

Where you can run in the directory that has your many *.dat files. If you put this in a script called `uniq_dat`, and make it executable, you can run it like:

```
uniq_dat *.dat
```

Comment: You should use `for f in "$@"` or just plain the shorthand `for f`. The special variable `$*` does not handle whitespace etc correctly. Similarly, you should use double quotes around `$f` everywhere, unless you specifically want the shell to split the value into multiple tokens on `IFS`.

Comment: I'd use `mktemp` to create the temporary file in the same directory, and `mv` instead of `cp` since you're going to overwrite the original anyway.

Comment: @chepner: `mv` seems like an unnecessary optimization. If `/tmp` is on a different disk it won't be any faster.

Comment: That's one reason I suggested making the temp file in the current directory, but I agree, it's minor.

Comment: One advantage to using cp is that it will not break hardlinks.

Answer (score 9):

use sort!

```
sort -u foo -o foo
# is short for
sort --unique foo -o foo

# if you want to avoid sorting
sort --merge --unique foo -o foo
```